# How can a moderator delete an old post on Yahoo! Groups?

Tags: mailing-list, forums, yahoo-groups

I am the owner and moderator of a group on Yahoo! Groups.  The group has tens of thousands of messages, and I need to delete a few individual, very old messages posted by someone whose Yahoo! account has been deleted.  How can I do this?

According to [Yahoo! Help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/groups/delete-message-sln4076.html), posters can delete their own messages by opening them in the web interface and pressing the "Delete" button which appears at the bottom.  Though I know the URLs of all the messages I need to delete, this technique doesn't seem to work for moderators; for me pressing the "Delete" button has no effect.  And the original poster cannot delete his own messages because [there is no way to reactivate an account which has been dormant for more than a year](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2624.html).

The same Yahoo! Help article says that moderators can delete a message from the message list by ticking the checkbox next to its entry and then pressing the "Delete" button at the top of the page.  However, in Yahoo! Groups's new interface, the message list is now one of those infinitely scrolling pages.  In my case I would have to scroll and manually look through *tens of thousands* of archived messages in order to get to the ones I want to delete.  Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Yahoo! Groups appears to have solved the problem; the "Delete" button now works as expected.  Is anyone else continuing to experience the issue?